# How to avoid output of a referenced file in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to reference a typescript file without including its output when the js file is created.

```
/// <reference path="foo.ts" />

class Bar
{ }
```

The tsconfig.json only references bar.ts

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "outFile": "bar.js",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "files": [
    "bar.ts"
  ]
}
```

When the project is built, bar.js contains statements from both foo.ts and bar.ts when I only want it to include content from bar.ts.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Then why are you including it in the first place? You probably want to have a foo-interface.ts file that contains only the interface you want.